# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.OrderDetails_dbo.Order_OrderId' on table 'OrderDetails' may cause

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, cascading-deletes

I'm getting this error message from the PMC:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.OrderDetails_dbo.Order_OrderId' on table 'OrderDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I found a post here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) with an accepted answer, but it didn't work for me.

These are my tables:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class Order
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }      

    public virtual List<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}


[Table("OrderDetails")]
public class OrderDetails
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

The `FluentApi`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Order)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

If an `OrderDetails` gets deleted, I don't want the `Order` to be deleted. But the other way around is fine with me.

So what's wrong with what I tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

I kept running the command `Update-Database` which executes the last generated migrations file.

I deleted the last migration file I created, and ran the command `Add-Migration` again which generated a new file with my latest `modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>()...` (`FluentApi`) code changes I made.

Then ran the command `Update-Database` and it worked!

So what I didn't know was that every time you change something in

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { ... }`,

you need to execute `Add-Migration filename` again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.WithMany()` without parameter is wrong here. Because `Order.OrderDetails` represents the inverse navigation property of the relationship you must use...

```
.WithMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
```

Comment: I have tried that one too, but it gave me the exact same error message. Then I tried with no parameters.