# Database design for storing user images

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6

I am building web application that allow users to upload their images.
Images can be of different types (recipes, articles, tips ... and **profile images**).
I have a little confusion about Profile Images.
I am using entity framework code first and I can't model **1-0 or 1**.
But I have made a relation like on the image bellow and I need confirmation about this design is it good or bad? Does it have some flaws?
*User can upload any type of image and I know who uploaded image based on `CreatedBy` Field.

And user can upload profile image and in that case in application I will just update `ImageId` field in Users table.*
[image]

Comment: 1 : 0-1 does work in EF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional   in principal what you are trying is Ok in my view

Comment: What do you mean, "1-0 or 1"? Do you mean, 1-0:1? What do you mean you "can't" you model it?

Comment: It seems that I confused my self and make much noise about simple thing. I aleady have 1-n and was trying to make 1-0:1 to same table. I just want to know is this design good for what I described in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two entity types, users and images; hence tables AspUsers & Image. You have relationships (in the everyday/ER sense): UserCreatedImage(UserId,ImageId) and UserProfileImage(UserId,ImageId).

The first is many:many in entities so gets its own table.

The second is 0-or-1:1 in images:users aka 1:0-or-1 in users:images. That is typically expressed by an ImageId column in AspUsers that is a nullable foreign key to ImageId in Image.

Assuming you add that, your design is reasonable.

(Because of the FK cycle between these tables--which is the proper model--you must code in Entity Framework in a [certain way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths).)