# Many-To-Many Cascading Delete Breeze

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first, breeze

I have four entities A, B, C, and D.

A has many Bs and Cs.

B has many Ds.

And there is a many-to-many relationship between C and D.

This many-to-many relationship is in a join table exposed to Breeze as an entity CD.

I want to establish a cascading delete so that deleting the first entity in any of the following rows yields that cascading delete.

```
A -> B -> D -> CD

B -> D -> CD

D -> CD

A -> C -> CD

C -> CD
```

All the other foreign keys have a cascading delete except for A -> C. Every time I attempt to set this as a cascading delete SQL Server 2012 gives me the following error:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_dbo.C_dbo.A_AId'.   Introducing
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.C_dbo.A_AId' on table 'C' may cause
>   cycles or multiple     cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint. See previous errors.

How can I resolve this error and get close to what I'm looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Answer (score 0):

As there multiple cascade paths, SQL server is complaining about ON DELETE CASCADE OPTION

one path  C->CD and another C->A->B->D->CD

you can just define foreign key with out ON DELETE CASCADE option

you can create INSETAD OF DELETE trigger on the table C and delete the corresponding row in table A

Comment: Perhaps my use of arrows was not correct. CD holds a foreign key to both C and D, not the other way around. How would I deal with that then? Create a BEFORE DELETE trigger on A that deletes the row in C?

Comment: Oops, I meant INSTEAD OF DELETE in my comment above. Also this still won't work for me because A is itself has a FK with a cascade delete. Looks like I'll have to push the delete logic to the application.

Comment: @user1569339, yes you are right, have a stored procedure which does this deletion and call it from your application layer.

Comment: Or perhaps I could have the records in C orphaned and delete them subsequently with an AFTER DELETE trigger.