# ASP.NET MVC cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two models.
Town:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CpuRegistry.Models
{    
  public enum TownType
  {
      Город, Посёлок, Село
  }

  public class Town
  {
      public int ID { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public int RegionID { get; set; }

      public int? DistrictID { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public TownType TownType { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }        
      public virtual ICollection<Primary> Primaries { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and District:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CpuRegistry.Models
{
    public class District
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RegionID { get; set; }

        public int? TownID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Town> Towns { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Primary> Primaries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Town can belong to District. Disctrict can belong to Town. Also District can have few towns, Town can have few districts.
As you can see, I marked DistrictID and TownID with "?".

When I use command Add-Migration, Visual Studio create migration file, which contains:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.TownDistricts",
                c => new
                    {
                        Town_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        District_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Town_ID, t.District_ID })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Towns", t => t.Town_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Districts", t => t.District_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.Town_ID)
                .Index(t => t.District_ID);
```

After using command Update-Database, I have next error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.TownDistricts_dbo.Districts_District_ID' on table 'TownDistricts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I saw this link: [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)
Quote from solution:

> You must either make the Stage optional in at least one of the entities (i.e. remove the [Required] attribute from the Stage properties)

But I don't have [Required] attribute.
Also I tried this solution:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Town>().HasRequired(t => t.Districts).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<District>().HasRequired(d => d.Towns).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

And have error:

> CpuRegistry.DataContexts.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   CpuRegistry.DataContexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

And when I open migration file, which creates user tables, I saw something similar to my code:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.RoleId);
```

But I cannot find, how developers solved this in models or something else.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the final classes, which solves my first question and problems from messages above, are:

```
namespace CpuRegistry.DataContexts
{
    public class CpuRegistryDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public CpuRegistryDb()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static CpuRegistryDb Create()
        {
            return new CpuRegistryDb();
        }

        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Town> Towns { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Town>().HasMany<District>(t => t.Districts).WithOptional(d => d.Town);
            modelBuilder.Entity<District>().HasMany<Town>(d => d.Towns).WithOptional(t => t.District);            
        }
    }
}

namespace CpuRegistry.Models
{
    public enum TownType
    {
        Город, Посёлок, Село
    }

    public class Town
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RegionID { get; set; }

        public int? DistrictID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public TownType TownType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
        public virtual District District { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ID.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class District
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RegionID { get; set; }

        public int? TownID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Town> Towns { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
        public virtual Town Town { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ID.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks @Hoborg for help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Configure Many-to-Many relationship using Code First Approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) you do not need explicit foreign key declaration `public int? TownID { get; set; }` in class `District` and vice versa (in another class). It seems that Entity Framework is able to configure all necessary connections (additional table in database) just using declared navigation collections like `public virtual ICollection<Town> Towns { get; set; }`.

**Addition**. What do you mean when declare both single property `public int? DistrictID { get; set; }` and a collection `public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }`. Do you confuse the concepts of many-to-many relationship in EF or did you mean that these properties denote something different? If they denote something different then you should use Fluent API to configure them properly.

**Update**. After OP's clarifications I suggest the following code.

```
public class TestEfContext : ApplicationDbContext {
    public DbSet<Town> Towns { get; set; }
    public DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Town>()
            .HasMany<District>(x => x.Districts)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Town);

        modelBuilder.Entity<District>()
            .HasMany<Town>(x => x.Towns)
            .WithOptional(x => x.District);
    }
}

public class Town {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public District District { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Id.ToString();
    }
}

public class District {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Town Town { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Town> Towns { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Thus

```
using (var ctx = new TestEfContext()) {
            ctx.Towns.First().District = ctx.Districts.First();
        }
```

entails that the Town1 will have District = Distr1 and empty Districts collection while the Distr1 will have Town = null and Towns collection with one element - Town1.

Comment: `public int? DistrictID` means, that Town can belong to District (be a part of district).
`public virtual ICollection<District> Districts` means, that Town can have districts.

In human language: regions are devided by towns and districts. Usually, district include many towns. But some big towns do not belong to any district and are divided by districts.

Comment: I drew a 
[diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1bFjCWahknXSVhSRkczTWx2blE/view?usp=sharing). :)

Comment: @SergeyShambal I have updated my answer after your explanations. Is it the thing what you needed? If yes then don't you think that such design (one-to-many and reverse many-to-one) is not looking very well?

Comment: I tried your solution and the result looks like what I need. Thank you very much.
Yes, I think that such design is not a good idea. But diagram in my previous message is from real life, and I don't know how to describe it in another way.

Comment: After few days of development I got some problem. When I need to set Town in District model via DropDownList, model does not pass validation, because DropDownList contains ID's of towns, but model await for full class Town. I combined your solution with my previous variant. The result is in my next answer.