# Getting "Foreign Key constraint" even though cascade delete is turned off

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following user model:

```
 public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location")]
        public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MainPhoneNumber")]
        public Guid? MainPhoneNumberId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Mailbox")]
        public Guid? MailboxId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Fax")]
        public Guid? FaxId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Conference")]
        public Guid? ConferenceId { get; set; }

        public virtual PhoneNumber MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual PhoneNumber Mailbox { get; set; }
        public virtual PhoneNumber Fax { get; set; }
        public virtual PhoneNumber Conference { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AddOn> AddOns { get; set; }
    }
```

I also added the following rules using Fluent Api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                           .HasRequired(usr=>usr.Location)
                           .WithMany()
                           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                        .HasOptional(usr => usr.Fax)
                        .WithMany()
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                      .HasOptional(usr => usr.Conference)
                      .WithMany()
                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                      .HasOptional(usr => usr.Mailbox)
                      .WithMany()
                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                      .HasOptional(usr => usr.MainPhoneNumber)
                      .WithMany()
                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I would expect that these fluent rules will help me with any Cascade delete - problems. But still I receive the following error when trying to run "`Update-Database`" inside the console:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.User_dbo.PhoneNumber_FaxId'
>   on table 'User' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Note: Please be aware that **this is NOT a duplicate from that question**: [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

As you can see: The suggestions made there in the most topvoted answer are already included in my code (Fluent part)

(Update) THis is the PhoneNumber Class:

```
public class PhoneNumber
    {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("PhoneNumberPool")]
            public Guid PhoneNumberPoolId { get; set; }
            public virtual PhoneNumberPool PhoneNumberPool { get; set; }

            public int Length { get; set; }     

        }
```

PhoneNumberPool itself has a few simple properties (string, int, etc.) and a reference to "Location" (as well as the User).

Comment: This is really about cycles, not cascade deletion per se.

Comment: I would assume you have to specify the multiplicity at the other end, so `Locations => Users`

Comment: This is a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: @Noel No. It isn't at all. The answers on your linked question are already included in my code.

Comment: what does `PhoneNumber` look like?

Comment: why is PhoneNumber not a complextype (if it has a defined structure)?

Comment: I think your issues arise from that duel reference to `Location` then. If both `User` and `PhoneNumber` use it

Comment: You need to specify that `PhoneNumberPool => Location` will not cascade on delete

Comment: Ok. Got it. It was a 100% human error. I did not realize I have to run "Add-Migration" after each change in the fluent part before entering "Update-Database". Just glad, comments cannot be downvoted.  :) Sorry guys, and thanks for your time

Comment: I'm going to remember that one for future questions

Answer (score -1):

will this datamodel work for you?

this way you can add new types of phone numbers

```
    public enum PhoneNumberType {Main, Mailbox, Fax, Conference, Other}


PhoneNumber{
     public PhoneNumberType  NumberType{get;set;};
     public string Number{get;set;};
    //other properties

    public virtual User{get;set;}
    }

    public class User
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("Location")]
            public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
            public Location Location { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public virtual List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<AddOn> AddOns { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: if the datamodel is revised and avoid unncessary child tables, that is better approach i believe

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to change my data structure for a problem that SHOULD be solvable