# How to allow multiple FK in a table to cascade on delete?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-fluent-api

I'm not certain if the title is correct as I'm unsure if the diagnostics of mine are reliable. Feel free to comment on that.

While declaring a table using Fluent API like so:

```
CreateTable("dbo.Things",
  c => new
  {
    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
    UnoId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
    DuoId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
  })
  .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
  .ForeignKey("dbo.Unos", t => t.UnoId, cascadeDelete: true)
  .ForeignKey("dbo.Duos", t => t.DuoId, cascadeDelete: true)
  .Index(t => t.UnoId)
  .Index(t => t.DuoId);
}
```

there's this error message when I try to update the DB.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Things_dbo.Duos_DuoId' on table 'Things' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I noticed that when I switch the order of assignment of the FK (letting *Duos* go before *Unos*), I get the same error message but complaining about *Unos* instead.

Not being entirely certain why this happens, I sense that the foreign key doesn't thrive when set to two tables. However, I'm not sure if I should set cascading to off or if I'm better off doing something more complex to the set of FKs.

Not being fully sure what the computer is worried about, I guess that I'd like the cascading on deletion to stay in effect. If I remove either *Uno* or *Duo* that the thing relies on, I want that thing to be gone.

How do I do that? Or should I consider other aspects as well?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127512/1525840), the user explains the problem very clearly (it's fully applicable to my case). However, disabling the cascading for any of those two that things depend on is something I want to avoid. I want it to be removed if **any** of those are removed.

Comment: It's a SQL Server restriction you have to live with. You need triggers to get the desired behavior. But are you absolutely sure that if an `Uno` is deleted, it's OK that a `Duo` also suddenly loses some if its `Thing`s?

Comment: Oh, that's why... I am sure about the loss. However, I went with the easiest way out and turned off cascading for the entity that's least likely to be deleted first. Also - you've got a godlike reputation right now - 48888, which is four-eights. nice.