# Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

i have many classes but in `PorductionLine` and `Machine` I have some problems. ProductionLine Class is:

```
[Column("FldKeyId")]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Required]
   [Key]
   public int MyKeyId { get; set; }
   [Column("FldCode")]
    [Required]
   [Index(IsUnique = true)]
   public int MyCode
   {
       get { return _Code; }
       set { _Code = value; }
   }
   [Column("FldName")]
    [Required]
   public string MyName
   {
       get { return _Name; }
       set { _Name = value; }
   }
   [Column("FldLocation")]
    [Required]
   public string MyLocation
   {
       get { return _Location; }
       set { _Location = value; }
   }

   [Column("FldCompanyKey")]
   public int MyCompanyKey { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("MyCompanyKey")]
    [Required]
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

And Machine Class is:

```
[Column("FldKeyId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int MyKeyId { get; set; }
    [Column("FldCode")]
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int MyMachineCode
    {
        get { return _MachineCode; }
        set { _MachineCode = value; }
    }
    [Column("FldName")]
    [Required]
    public string MyName
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    [Column("FldProductionLineKey")]

    public int MyProductionLineKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MyProductionLineKey")]
    //[Required]
    public ProductionLine ProductionLine { get; set; }
```

when I want generate database form this classes I have this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.TblMachine_dbo.TblProductionLine_FldProductionLineKey' on
>   table 'TblMachine' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
when I comment this 3 lines

```
[Column("FldProductionLineKey")]
public int MyProductionLineKey { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("MyProductionLineKey")]
```

error is gone but I want this codes cus in some other classes I have this problem...
what I have to do?
thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot
>   appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential
>   actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement.
>   For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have
>   one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions
>   tree.

You can set cascadeDelete to false or true (in your migration Up() method). Depends upon your requirement.

```
AddForeignKey(..., cascadeDelete: false);
```

for more information check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: ok for one time it worked but it a business program and in costumer system I want crate database with `database.CreateIfNotExist` is Attribute or something like this that I put in my class that worked as `cascadeDelete: false`

Comment: @sadeq you can do it in fluent mapping