# SQL Server - Cyclic Cascade Path

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, join, table-relationships

Lets say I have two tables - **User** and **Post**

I introduced a customized Join table **Vote** to have a many-to-many relationship between **User** and **Post**.

The tables have following structure:

- **User** (*UseId*, Name)
- **Post** (*PostId*, UserId, Content)
- **Vote**(*Id*, UserId, PostId, Value)

Notes:

- The emphasized columns of each table is a `PK`.
- The `UserId` in **Post** is a `FK` to **User** table.
- The `UserId` and `PostId` columns in **Vote** table are `FK` to the
  respective tables.
- Other columns like `Value`, `Content`, `Name`, etc. are varchar.

---

Considering the above design is appropriate (if not, suggestions are welcomed :) .....

What I want is:

1. If a row in **Post** Table is deleted, the related row in **Vote** should also be deleted.
2. If a row in **User** Table is deleted, the related row in **Vote** should also be deleted.
3. If a row in **User** Table is deleted, the related row's `UserId` column in **Post** should be set to NULL.

Can I achieve such kind of relationships, without any `Cyclic-Redundancy`? If yes, How?

---

UPDATE:

Check out this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127512/4062881) if you too have faced multiple cascade paths:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for cascading foreign key relationships.  For the first two:

```
alter table vote
    add constraint fk_vote_user
        foreign key (userid) references user(userid) on delete cascade;

alter table vote
    add constraint fk_vote_post
        foreign key (postid) references post(postid) on delete cascade;
```

For the third:

```
alter table post
    add constraint fk_post_user
        foreign key (userid) references user(userid) on delete set null;
```

These are explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx).

Comment: You forgot the `references` parts, or am I missing something?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried the cascading foreign keys, but I ended up with cyclic-redundancies. I'll try it your way and see :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff It sure worked, thanks!  I had messed up with the relationships and got stuck with cyclic paths.. its done now..

Comment: @VijayChavda . . . Glad I could help.  Foreign key relationships can get confusing, especially when you are trying to manage multiple relationships.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, my actual schema is pretty complex. I have like, 12 tables linked to my User table, and the design is getting really crazy!!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add `isdeleted bit, changed datetime` columns to each table and use triggers to update column values on delete. In that case you will keep history of your votes, posts and users.

Or just on delete triggers.

Or to use cascade relationship as Gordon Linoff posted.