# How to debug Entity Framework Code First database deployment error?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure

How do I debug an error with my Entity Framework Code First database deployment?

I'm using EF 6.1.3. I'm trying to deploy a database to Azure that includes the following model:

```
public class DriverLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

    public int RouteID { get; set; }
    public virtual Route Route { get; set; }

    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverID")]
    public virtual Employee Driver { get; set; }

    public int DispatcherID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DispatcherID")]
    public virtual Employee Dispatcher { get; set; }
}
```

The deployment succeeds, but when I try to access the database, I get the following error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

If I remove the last two fields -- DispatcherID and Dispatcher -- I do not get this error.

For some reason, EF does not like my including these two fields, but I don't know why, and I don't know how to go about debugging this.

Comment: How do you host your application, so that you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<DriverLog>()
            .HasRequired(o => o.Dispatcher)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Credit for this solution goes to: [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths?rq=1)

Comment: Great! me was near.. happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Do check primary key constraint for  'DispatcherID', basicaly the order its creating the table, as you are using 'DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges'.

Also inject some custom error catch, to have detail error information.