# Foreign key constraint exception in basic table design

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core and have a simple 5 table design, but get an error and can't figure out why. What am I missing?

**Exception:**

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_GraphicItems_GraphicUploadTemplateItems_GraphicUploadTemplateItemId'
>   on table 'GraphicItems' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

**Base:**

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client : Base
{
    public Guid Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Graphic:**

```
public class Graphic : Base
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GraphicItem> Items { get; set; } = new HashSet<GraphicItem>();
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new HashSet<Tag>();
}
```

**GraphicItem:** *(the property GraphicUploadTemplateId causes the exception)*

```
public class GraphicItem : Base
{
    public int GraphicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Graphic Graphic { get; set; }
    public int GraphicUploadTemplateItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual GraphicUploadTemplateItem UploadTemplateItem { get; set; }
}
```

**GraphicUploadTemplate:**

```
public class GraphicUploadTemplate : Base
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client client { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<GraphicUploadTemplateItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**GraphicUploadTemplateItem:**

```
public class GraphicUploadTemplateItem : Base
{
    public int GraphicUploadTemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual GraphicUploadTemplate UploadTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a link to the corresponding GraphicUploadTemplateItem already through GraphicItem.UploadTemplateItem.Id, i think that causes the circular reference.

Comment: ah yes off course! sorry for beeing blind ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by setting the property type to nullable

```
public class GraphicItem : Base
{
    public int GraphicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Graphic Graphic { get; set; }
    public int? GraphicUploadTemplateItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual GraphicUploadTemplateItem UploadTemplate { get; set; }
}
```