# Disable cascade delete on EF Core 2 globally

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to know about ways of disabling cascade delete in `EF Core 2` globally. Any help is appricated.

In EF 6.x we used following code to disable cascade delete on both `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany` realtions:

```
builder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
builder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3815#issuecomment-159059491

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Unfortunately EF Core currently (latest at this time v2.0) does not expose a good way to control the conventions globally.

The default EF Core 2.0 convention is to use `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` for required and `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` for optional relationships. What I can suggest as workaround is a typical metadata model loop at the end of the `OnModelCreating` override. In this case, locating all the already discovered relationships and modifying them accordingly:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    var cascadeFKs = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
        .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
        fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does `cascadeFKs` here contains only 'one-to-many' relations or it also includes 'many-to-many' relations too?

Comment: There is no special `many-to-many` relationships in EFC currently (they are emulated with 2 `one-to-many`). So to answer your question, `cascadeFks` contains all relationships - `one-to-many` and `one-to-one`.

Comment: @AuthorProxy There is no *onUpdateBehavior* in EF Core. The only update option is `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`. You can see the current EFC options and their relational mapping here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521939/efcore-nullable-relationship-setting-ondelete-referentialaction-restrict/48523214#48523214. If you are trying to model mutable PK, it's not supported at all.

Comment: @IvanStoev The default behavior for required relationship is `Cascade` according to [the current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#required-relationships)

Comment: @GGirard Indeed, that's what I meant to write, `Restrict` is typo (shame on me), thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @IvanStoev, is [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3815#issuecomment-432969798) valid? If so, would it be appropriate to include `.Where(e => !e.IsOwned())` in your answer?

Comment: @MattJenkins I believe `!fk.IsOwnership` does the same

Comment: as of efcore3, restrict behavior has changed.  The new one to use that is identical to what restrict was at the time of writing this answer is: ClientNoAction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#deletebehaviorrestrict-has-cleaner-semantics

Comment: @IvanStoev To your knowledge, did this behavior change since the answer was written (i.e. there's still no way to alter the built-in conventions)?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to disable the "cascade delete" convention in EF Core 7 using the following code on my `DbContext` type:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Remove(typeof(CascadeDeleteConvention));
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Remove(typeof(SqlServerOnDeleteConvention));
}
```

Hopefully this is useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ComandaPlato", x => x.ComandaPlatoId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ComandaPlato_Comanda_ComandaId",
                        column: x => x.ComandaId,
                        principalTable: "Comanda",
                        principalColumn: "ComandaId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);//default: cascade on
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ComandaPlato_Plato_PlatoId",
                        column: x => x.PlatoId,
                        principalTable: "Plato",
                        principalColumn: "PlatoId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);//turn off cascade,"by hand"
                });
//comments: modifing the auto-generated migration, "harcode by hand" this attibute, as view bellow: change "Cascade" to "NoAction" (as view 1st and 2st examples)
```

Answer (score -3):

May be It helps:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
ChangeTracker.CascadeDeleteTiming = ChangeTracking.CascadeTiming.Never;
ChangeTracker.DeleteOrphansTiming = ChangeTracking.CascadeTiming.Never;
}
```

Comment: You're not even allowed to do this. You get: `InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point`