# EFCore nullable relationship setting onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm running efcore 2.0.1.

I have a model:

```
public class BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<YummyPunyPrey> YummyPunyPrey { get; set; }
}
public class YummyPunyPrey
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeethId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeethId")]
    public BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth { get; set; }

}
```

I have no fluent api on these two classes. But when I generate a migration

```
constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_YummyPunyPrey", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_YummyPunyPrey_BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth_BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeethId",
                    column: x => x.BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeethId,
                    principalTable: "BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Why is it generating *onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict* when the documentation says it should handle it as a *ClientSetNull*

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete
>
> Behavior Name **|** Effect on dependent/child in memory   **|** Effect on dependent/child in database
>
> ClientSetNull (Default) **|** Foreign key properties are set to null **|** None
>
> Changes in EF Core 2.0: In previous releases, Restrict would cause optional foreign key properties in tracked dependent entities to be set to null, and was the default delete behavior for optional relationships. In EF Core 2.0, the ClientSetNull was introduced to represent that behavior and became the default for optional relationships. The behavior of Restrict was adjusted to never have any side effects on dependent entities.

Any help as to why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EF Core 2.0.1 metadata and migrations use different enums for specifying the delete behavior - respectively [`DeleteBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-2.0) and [`ReferentialAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.referentialaction?view=efcore-2.0). While the first is well documented, the second and the mapping between the two is not (at the time of writing).

Here is the current mapping:

```
DeleteBehavior    ReferentialAction
==============    =================
Cascade           Cascade
ClientSetNull     Restrict
Restrict          Restrict
SetNull           SetNull
```

In your case, the relationship is [*optional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships), hence the `DeleteBehavior` by convention is `ClientSetNull` which maps to `onDelete: Restrict`, or in other words, *enforced* (enabled) FK w/o cascade delete.

If you want different behavior, you have to use fluent API, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth>()
    .HasMany(e => e.YummyPunyPrey)
    .WithOne(e => e.BigAwesomeDinosaurWithTeeth)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull); // or whatever you like
```

Comment: Golden statues should be made in your honor; thank you Ivan! The documentation really threw me off.

I was trying to avoid the API but I've already broke that resolution many times so another won't hurt.