# EF Core relationship throwing error when creating the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an `Address` class, that I use in a `Customer` class and in an `Order` class:

```
public class Address
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set }
    ...
}

public class Customer
{
    ...
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
    ...
    public Customer Curstomer { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set;}
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set;}
}
```

I created the migrations succesfully but when I try to `update-database` I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_Order_Address_ShippingAddressId' on table 'Order' may cause cycles
>   or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create
>   constraint or index. See previous errors.

What is the correct way of setting up such relationship? Is this modelling even correct? Because it seems strange to me that `Address` is a property related to `Customer`, but I'm also using it on `Order`, but duplicating the addresses in an `OrderAddresses` table seems wrong too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, change the `ReferentialAction` for the `onDelete` of your foreign key in the migration to something other than `Cascade`. `Restrict` is probably a good option. It will look something like this:

```
constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Order", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Orders_BillingAddress_BillingAddressId",
                    column: x => x.BillingAddressId,
                    principalTable: "Addresses",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            }
```

Just change that to `Restrict` or another choice.

**Why?**

If you have `Cascade`, suppose you were to delete the `BillingAddress` of your `Order`. That would try to cascade the delete to the `Order` which would then cascade *its* delete to the `ShippingAddress` which would then try to cascade *that* delete back to the Order and so on and so forth, hence why SQL Server correctly errors out on cyclical cascading deletes.

See also this question: [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: Manually editing the migration file worked. But, do you know how could I to this using fluent configuration? To use the `.OnDelete()` method in the `OnModelCreatingMethod` method, I need to do something like this `builder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.ShippingAddress).WithOne(x => x.??????).OnDelete(xxxx)`. But I don't have a reference to the `Order` class int the `Address` class. The `Address` class references the `Customer` class.

Comment: Hum, just discovered that I don't have to inform the parameters of the second part. So this worked: `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.ShippingAddress).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`. Thanks