# How to turn on CASCADE in SQL Server 2008 table relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cascade

I have 5 tables that are connected together:

```
Table A
Table B
Table C
Table D
Table E
```

- Table A `PK` is `Code` column.
- Table B `PK` is `Code` column.
- Table C `PK` is `Number` column.
- Table D `PK` is `Number` column.
- Table E `PK` is `Name` column.

Relationship between the tables above is next:

- Table A `PK` has `FK` in Table B `ACode` column
- Table A `PK` has `FK` in Table C `ACode` column
- Table A `PK` has `FK` in Table E `ACode` column
- Table B `PK` has `FK` in Table C `BCode` column
- Table B `PK` has `FK` in Table E `BCode` column
- Table C `PK` has `FK` in Table D `CNumber` column

This part above was pretty simple to organize in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Now I would like to create CASCADE on Update on all `FK` columns. For example if `PK` in Table A gets updated all other `FK` in other columns (B,C and E) should update as well. Is this something that would be recommended and how I can achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done when creating the PK-FK relationship but you should be able to do it later.  See [ALTER TABLE table_constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

In your case, something like this ought to do it:

```
ALTER TABLE CONSTRAINT -- name of your PK constraint
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED|NOCLUSTERED (...) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ...
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: It seems that I can not have On Update Cascade on two different `FK` relationships in the same table. Is there any reason why SQL doesn't let me do that? Also is there another solution for this situation?

Comment: there's a good discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: The solution often recommended is to use triggers for the second and subsequent FKs