# 'FK_Ratings_Users_UserId' on table 'Ratings' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying in **.NET EFCore** the following **Code-First** migrations through the entities below

### User

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(8), MaxLength(16)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(6), MaxLength(15)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Apartment> Apartments { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

### Apartment

```
[Table("Apartments")]
public class Apartment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(24), MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(24), MaxLength(250)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AptCateg> AptsCategs { get; set; }
}
```

### Ratings

```
[Table("Ratings")]
public class Rating
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Apartment")]
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }

    public Apartment Apartment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I use the commands `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase` but when I try to use `dotnet ef database update` it throws the following error in cmd, as in the title

> 'FK_Ratings_Users_UserId' on table 'Ratings' may cause cycles or
>   multiple cascade paths

I tried adding as in the **EFCore** tutorial from [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) the modelBuilder's Cascade behavior but it doesn't work because I am getting the same error. I have also tried doing the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) but the implementation for `HasRequired` isn't working even if try to install `EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`.

I understand that there is an issue with a circular *thingy* going on. From my intuition the program doesn't know what to do in the case of deleting a user, if to drop or not its ratings and apartments or some of that sort, and this is why its acting this way but I can't fix the problem.

My question is, how can I solve this issue as I cannot create my database, and thus I cannot continue working on the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make the user relationship optional on one of the tables like:

```
public int? UserId { get; set; }
```

Making the property type nullable tells EF that a cascade delete is not required here.

Comment: This works. I've read something, somewhere, about making the FK nullable but I wasn't sure about it. Should have tried from the beginning but at least other people will see this question, and get their issue solved as too.

Thanks a lot! Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are causing a cyclic reference by adding the *User* and *Apartment* to the *Ratings* entity. *User* and *Apartment* entities already have a one-to-many relationship to the *Ratings* collection.

> 'FK_Ratings_Users_UserId' on table 'Ratings' may cause cycles or
>   multiple cascade paths

This is how the *Ratings* entity should look like:

```
[Table("Ratings")]
public class Rating
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @vladel let me know if my suggestion fixes the EF error.

Comment: Why would the Rating table should be like this? It wouldn't have any connection with the other tables if it doesn't implement navigation properties at least. I need the Ratings table because a User can leave a rating on an Apartment and I need to determine if he rated or not an apartment in order to prevent him from over-rating.
Thanks any way for the help.