# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'XYZ_ID' on table 'XXX' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first-mapping

I am getting this error in code first MVC CORE while inserting this and 
I am doing Code first for very first Time 
command:

```
Update-Database -Context ProjectDbContext
```

> "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Product_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' 
>   on table 'Product' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify 
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY 
>   constraints".

My Classes are are given below and also explain me why we use association in mvc model classes like this :

```
public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

Or
public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }

public virtual Icollection<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }



public class Product
{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductModel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quatity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductColor { get; set; }

    public byte Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime TodayDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SubCategoryName { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public ICollection< Category> Category { set; get; }

    public ICollection<Product> Product { set; get; }
}  


public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)  ?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Product` and `SubCategory`? Will one product must have `SubCategory`?

Comment: Share us your code in `ProjectDbContext`. I fail to reproduce your issue with `    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
`

Comment: these are my classes          public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

       


    }

        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

        public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }

     
    }

Comment: Problem Solved by removing required on CategoryId and SubcategoryId.

Answer (score 0):

add Following in identity model file under ApplicationDbContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

hope this will help but your cascade delete will be off.

Comment: DbModelBuilder is not existing. Can you tell me its assembly/dll name?  If I am using ModelBuilder then Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>() is not exiting.