# asp.net mvc (Migration)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I crete table in asp.net mvc but when i crete the migration this error message show

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.DailyTransactions_dbo.Contracts_ContractId' on table 'DailyTransactions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

this is DailyTransactions table :

```
 public class DailyTransactions
{
    [Key]
    public int DailyTransactions_Id { get; set; }

    public double Account { get; set; }

    public string Account_Name { get; set; }

    public double Debit { get; set; }

    public double Credit { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customers customers { get; set; }

    public int ContractId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContractId")]
    public virtual Contracts contracts { get; set; }

}
```

and this contract table :

```
 public class Contracts
{
    [Key]
    public int Contracts_Id { get; set; }

    public int Contract_Num { get; set; }

    public DateTime Contract_Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime Contract_End { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

     public string TypeOfRent { get; set; }

    public double AmountOfRent { get; set; }

     public double Total { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customers customers { get; set; }

      public int sectionsId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("sectionsId")]
      public virtual Sections sections { get; set; }



}
```

Comment: Try adding `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` in `modelBuilder.Entity<DailyTransactions>()`, because you don't have any `[Required]` attribute annotations.

Comment: i don,t understand where i added

Comment: You need to add it inside `OnModelCreating` method (I assumed you're using Code First here). Also you may want to try `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: Thank you ,, i solve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off `CascadeDelete` for `DailyTransactions` and `Contracts`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DailyTransactions>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Contracts)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

For example:

```
public class YourDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public YourDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DailyTransactions>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Contracts)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK i will try .

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper I am glad to help you!:)