# Failed executing DbCommand-Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, .net-core

Here showing following error when going to update-database, through dotnet-core migration.

```
        Failed executing DbCommand (48ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        CREATE TABLE [DepartmentSchool] (
        [DepartmentID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        [SchoolsId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_DepartmentSchool] PRIMARY KEY ([SchoolsId], [DepartmentID]),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_DepartmentSchool_Department_DepartmentID] FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentID]) REFERENCES [Department] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT [FK_DepartmentSchool_School_SchoolsId] FOREIGN KEY ([SchoolsId]) REFERENCES [School] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Below is the entity relation class are:

**School** Class(First Table):

```
public partial class Schools
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DepartmentSchool> DepartmentSchools { get; set; } 
}
```

**Department** Class(Second Table):

```
public partial class Department
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DepartmentSchool> DepartmentSchools { get; set; } 
}
```

**DepartmentSchool** Class (Middle table)

```
public class DepartmentSchool
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        public Guid SchoolsId { get; set; }
        public Schools Schools { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the modulbulider it is relation is define here:

```
 //Many to many relationship between School and Depatment
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasKey(ds => new { ds.SchoolsId, ds.DepartmentID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasOne(ds => ds.Department)
            .WithMany(d => d.DepartmentSchools)
            .HasForeignKey(ds => ds.DepartmentID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasOne(ds => ds.Schools)
            .WithMany(d => d.DepartmentSchools)
            .HasForeignKey(ds => ds.SchoolsId);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_DepartmentSchool_School_SchoolsId' on table 'DepartmentSchool' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index.

Comment: The above problem occurs during the migration in dotnet core, when update database in the SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable cascading delete by allowing null values in the references.

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

[About Cascade Delete In Asp Core](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-cascade-delete)

For example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
            .HasOne(i => i.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.Invoices)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

[Help link about reason error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: You can not use IsRequired(). This Code Just an example.Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I added the code according to the accepted answer and it is working:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasKey(ds => new { ds.SchoolsId, ds.DepartmentID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasOne(ds => ds.Department)
            .WithMany(d => d.DepartmentSchools)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasForeignKey(ds => ds.DepartmentID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentSchool>()
            .HasOne(ds => ds.Schools)
            .WithMany(d => d.DepartmentSchools)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasForeignKey(ds => ds.SchoolsId);
```