# Database schema design by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design, database-schema

I have a problem with design DB schema when I try to build schema by db model ef.
I need to get a model according to this scheme:

[image]

My `DbContext`:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base("AppDbContext")
    {
        Database.Delete();
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public DbSet<A1> A1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<A2> A2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<A1_A2> A1_A2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> B { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> C { get; set; }
    public DbSet<D> D { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<A1>()
            .HasMany(a => a.A1_A2)
            .WithRequired(a => a.A1)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.A1_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<A2>()
            .HasMany(a => a.A1_A2)
            .WithRequired(a => a.A2)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.A2_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<A1_A2>()
            .HasMany(a => a.B)
            .WithRequired(a => a.A1A2)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.A1A2_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
            .HasMany(a => a.C)
            .WithRequired(a => a.B)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.B_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
            .HasMany(a => a.D)
            .WithRequired(a => a.B)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.B_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
            .HasMany(a => a.D)
            .WithRequired(a => a.C)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.C_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
public class Base
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A1 : Base
{
    public ICollection<A1_A2> A1_A2 { get; set; } = new HashSet<A1_A2>();
}

public class A2 : Base
{
    public ICollection<A1_A2> A1_A2 { get; set; } = new HashSet<A1_A2>();
}

public class A1_A2 : Base
{
    public A1 A1 { get; set; }
    public int A1_id { get; set; }
    public A2 A2 { get; set; }
    public int A2_id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<B> B { get; set; } = new HashSet<B>();
}

public class B : Base
{
    public A1_A2 A1A2 { get; set; }
    public int A1A2_id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<D> D { get; set; } = new HashSet<D>();
    public ICollection<C> C { get; set; } = new HashSet<C>();
}

public class C : Base
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public int B_id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<D> D { get; set; } = new HashSet<D>();
}

public class D : Base
{
    public C C { get; set; }
    public int C_id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public int B_id { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.D_dbo.B_B_id' on table 'D' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Please, this is a well-known exception. It shouldn't be hard to find a solution.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: @JamieBurns Thank you!
But if I need required foreign key between C and D and between B and D, there is no way to do it?

Comment: @Vadim, would you just need to configure that relationship to prevent cascades?