# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following classes with CODE FIRST:

```
public class License
{
    public License()
    {
        Assignments = new List<FeatureAssignment>();
    }

    public virtual List<FeatureAssignment> Assignments { get; set; }
    public bool CanExpire { get; set; }
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class FeatureAssignment
{
    public int FeatureAssignmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual License License { get; set; }
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }

    public virtual LicenseFeature LicenseFeature { get; set; }
    public int LicenseFeatureId { get; set; }
}
```

with

```
public class LicenseFeature
{
    public int LicenseFeatureId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(450)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product { get; set;}
}
```

last but not least

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get;set;}
    public string ProductName { get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LicenseFeature> LicenseFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

So the intention is to provide licenses for a dedicate product. Every license can have multiple feature assignment and a product can have multiple licenses.

Now when the DB is created I get the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.LicenseFeatures_dbo.Products_ProductId' on table 'LicenseFeatures' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Perhaps I miss the forrest for the trees, but I thought it should be possible to have feature assignement for a dedicated license? Did I miss an attribute for the foreign keys?

*********** UPDATE **********

I provided all affected classes. In the first posting the product class was missing - sorry for that :-(

Comment: The model you show doesn't have cycles or multiple reference paths between entities.

Comment: And in any case, it's probably a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths