# Using Mssql Cascade And Setnull Together

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an atm project, I want the program to retrieve the information of people registered in the database from there, for example, when a person pays their water debt, the debt is deleted, or when we delete the user, all his data is gone, I tried to do this using cascade and setnull at the same time, it does not give an error, I would be glad if you could help.

i am getting error like this;

'Musteri' table saved successfully

'Su' table

- Unable to create relationship 'FK_musteri_su'.

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_musteri_su' on table 'musteri' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO Action or ON Update NO Action, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Is this the same problem you're facing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.