# ASP.NET Core MVC error - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_mandate_details_merchants_MerchantId' on table 'mandate_details'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC I am doing EF code-first migrations:

```
public class Mandate
{
    public Mandate()
    {
        Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MandateDetail> MandateDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MandateDetail
{
    public MandateDetail()
    {
        Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MandateId { get; set; }
    public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
    public virtual Mandate Mandate { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant
{
    public Merchant()
    {
        Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public decimal ChargeValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Mandate> Mandates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MandateDetail> MandateDetails { get; set; }
}
```

When I did:

```
PM> add-migration -verbose
```

I got this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_mandate_details_merchants_MerchantId' on table 'mandate_details' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127512/524861

Answer (score 0):

Both classe Mandate and MandateDetails have the same

```
public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
```

you have to remove it from one of them. It causes cycles or multiple cascade path. I think it is better to remove from Mandate Details.