# How do I solve error: "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an SQL Server database using EF Core, code-first.

I am getting this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Images_Rabbits_AvatarId' on table 'Images' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

These are the relevant entities:

```cs
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Avatar? Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class User : Profile
{
    public virtual List<Rabbit> Rabbits { get; set; } = new List<Rabbit>();
}
```

```cs
public class Rabbit : Profile
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; } = new List<Image>();
}
```

```cs
public class Avatar : ImageBase
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Image : ImageBase
{
    public int RabbitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Rabbit Rabbit { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ImageBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths), which seems to be a similar problem, but I don't understand the solution. When a Rabbit is deleted I want both its avatar and images to be deleted.

I have tried set the foreign keys etc in Image and Avatar to nullable, but it didn't make a difference. I also don't know if I want to do that, because wouldn't that, for example, an Avatar can exist without a Profile?

If I've missed any information, please let me know. I am new to EF Core and programming in general (this project is for practice), so I'm sorry if there are any obvious problems that I've missed.

Comment: This is a SQL Server exception and there are tons of questions about it. The key is in: "Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION" which should be done by configuring some foreign keys in the EF model until there are no "cycles or multiple cascade paths".

Comment: Does FK_Images_Rabbits_AvatarId mean that the Rabbit foreign key on Images is called AvatarId? Because I can't find it in the migration file, it's called FK_Images_Rabbits_RabbitId there. I don't want Images to have a foreign key called AvatarId.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to arise from the relationships between Profile, User, Rabbit, Avatar, and Image. When a Rabbit is deleted, you want both its Avatar and Images to be deleted as well, but the way the relationships are set up may be causing EF Core to detect a cycle or multiple cascade paths.

To address this issue, you can manually configure the cascade delete behavior using the Fluent API in your DbContext class. Here are the steps to follow:

**Configure relationships**
First you need to overrid the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class and use the Fluent API to configure the relationships and their cascade behaviours explicitly.
**Set cascade delete behavior**
For the relationships that should not cause cascading deletes or where you want to avoid multiple cascade paths, set the cascade delete behavior to "NoAction"

Here is the configured OnModelCreating in your case:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Configure the User-Rabbit relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Rabbits)
        .WithOne(r => r.User)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ProfileId) // Assuming ProfileId exists in Rabbit for this FK relationship
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // This specifies that deleting a User deletes related Rabbits

    // Configure the Rabbit-Image relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Rabbit>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Images)
        .WithOne(i => i.Rabbit)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.RabbitId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Deleting a Rabbit deletes its Images

    // Configure the Profile-Avatar relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Avatar)
        .WithOne(a => a.Profile)
        .HasForeignKey<Avatar>(a => a.ProfileId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Deleting a Profile deletes its Avatar

    // For any relationships causing cycles or multiple cascade paths, consider setting to NoAction
    // Example:
    // .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

You will need to adjust the foreign key properties and relationships based on your actual entity definitions. The example above assumes a direct relationship between **"User"** and **"Rabbit"** through a **"ProfileId"** in **"Rabbit"**, which might not match your current setup.
Regarding your concern about making foreign keys nullable to solve the issue, it's generally not the best approach unless the business logic specifically allows for those entities to exist independently. For instance, making **strong text**AvatarId nullable in Profile would imply that a Profile can exist without an Avatar, which might not be what you want. It's better to solve the cascade delete issue through explicit configuration rather than changing the fundamental relationships between your entities unless required by your domain logic.

Answer (score 0):

-> In your case, Avatar and images have a foreign key relationship with Rabbit, because this creates multiple cascade paths.

-> Follow my way :- The Avatar and Images relationShip use cascade deleted (DeleteBehavior.Cascade) that means when Rabbit is deleted.its associated Avatar and Images will deleted automatically.

-> Code:-

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure cascade delete behavior for the Avatar relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Rabbit>()
        .HasOne(r => r.Avatar)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Rabbit>(r => r.AvatarId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Cascade delete for Avatar

    // Configure cascade delete behavior for the Image relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Rabbit>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Images)
        .WithOne(i => i.Rabbit)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.RabbitId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Cascade delete for Images

    // Configure other relationships...

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```