# EF Core creating unnecessary foreign key

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This is a continuation on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78082507/how-do-i-solve-error-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-mu).

I am trying to create an SQL Server database using EF Core, code-first.

I am getting this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Images_Rabbits_AvatarId' on table 'Images' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

These are the relevant entities:

```
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Avatar? Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User : Profile
{
    public virtual List<Rabbit> Rabbits { get; set; } = new List<Rabbit>();
}
```

```
public class Rabbit : Profile
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; } = new List<Image>();
}
```

```
public class Avatar : ImageBase
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Image : ImageBase
{
    public int RabbitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Rabbit Rabbit { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ImageBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried setting up the relationships explicitly with FluentAPI, but it hasn't made a difference. Mainly, I don't understand why EF Core (or SQL Server?) is creating the foreign key FK_Images_Rabbits_AvatarId. I don't want Images & Avatars to have a relationship, and since I have explicitly set up the relationship between Images and Rabbits (see below), I don't understand why it would create a key called AvatarId.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Rabbit>()
    .HasMany(r => r.Images)
    .WithOne(i => i.Rabbit)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.RabbitId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The foreign key is not present in the migration, it only appears as an error. I haven't been able to find it in SSMS, because even after having deleted the database, when regenerated, SSMS only shows the old tables.

I also don't know if my general setup is the best. I want both Users and Rabbits to have an Avatar, but I don't want Avatar to have separate foreign key columns for them, since an Avatar should only be tied to either a User or a Rabbit, not both. To solve this I have Users and Rabbits inherit from Profile, which specifies the relationship with Avatar, which then has a foreign key ProfileId. I have tried to remove the Profile inheritance and have Avatar have a column each for the two foreign keys, but it hasn't solved it. Still, I don't know if having separate foreign keys for User and Rabbit is the best strategy.

Essentially, I would like help with:

1. Why EF Core/SQL Server is creating a foreign key called FK_Images_Rabbits_AvatarId
2. If my general setup is good

Thank you for any help.

Edit:

This is what I want the relationships to look like (ImageBase is not included because it's not a table):
[image]

This is if Profile is included:
[image]

Comment: Can you attach what kind of table and columns you want to achieve when you're done? IMO your relations look suspicious but i'm not EF expert

Comment: What [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) mapping method do you use?

Comment: @siggemannen I've updated with images.

Comment: @Alex I hadn't done anything with it so I assume it's Table-per-hierarchy. I've tried specifically creating different tables for Users & Rabbits (e.g. modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users")), but it didn't make any difference.