# EF Core is creating a table not in the migration

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This is a continuation of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78082507/how-do-i-solve-error-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-mu/78107385#78107385). To troubleshoot I am trying to remove one of my tables, Images. I have removed the migrations and have removed the database in SSMS. When I create a new migration, Images is not mentioned. However, when I run the program, a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101], CREATE TABLE [Images], is run. Is this created from an old migration that I have not managed to delete? I have deleted the entire migrations folder.

Comment: Never delete migrations manually if you do not know what you are doing. You should have made edits to your classes as you wanted and do `Add-Migration name` and `Update-Database` so your migration delete those tables.

Command should not be ran if you have no migration file.

Since we do not know what you have manually done, my advice is to delete `Migrations` folder and delete whole database. After which you need to `Add-Migration InitialMigration` and see changes there if everything is okay before doing `Update-Database`

Comment: EF Core never creates or migrates database automatically at runtime. If you see `CREATE TABLE` command,  then there must be some code (your own or 3rd party library) which is calling `DbContext.Database.Migrate()`