# Foreign constraint error when running Seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an error when updating my database that is running the seed method.

This is my model Client:

```
   public int ClientID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public string portfolio
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int ProfilID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int RestrictionID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   public virtual Profil Profil
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Restriction Restriction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Restriction:

```
 public int RestrictionID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Restriction_name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   public int ProfilID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int RestrictionTypeID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Profil Profil
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual RestrictionType RestrictionType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Restriction_type { RestrictionTypeID, label}

then here is Profil{ ProfilID, Profil_name}

I don't know if the problem is because of the navigation properties ? I don't know what is happening here is my error message in the console:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Restriction_dbo.Profil_ProfilID' on table 'Restriction' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes it is entity framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: how to solve "FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489676/entity-framework-how-to-solve-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multi)

Comment: Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths