# EF Code First Error

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create some tables using Code First. Here is my code:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

When I Execute this code the following error occurs:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.State_dbo.Country_CountryId' on table 'State' may cause cycles
>   or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create
>   constraint. See previous errors.

But I want the CountryId in State Table to be a foreign key. What am I missing here? Can anybody guide me the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is worried about deletion here- because the `User` has a direct relationship to a `Country` and also a `State` and the `State` also relates to a `Country` you effectively have a potential loop of `User` -> `State` -> `Country` -> `User` which would mean that if cascade deletions were enabled the moment you deleted one user you would potentially delete everything in your database.

The answer is in the error message- by disabling cascade deletions across some of these relationships ( which is logical - deleting a user doesn't mean you want to delete their state and country ) you will avoid this risk. As you might imagine [this has come up on SO before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489676/entity-framework-how-to-solve-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multi)

As an aside, having the `Country` on the `User` and also on the `State` looks like questionable denormalisation - there may be a good reason for it, but that happens less often than you would expect.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Will this disable cascade deletes for any additional tables that I may add in future?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [CountryId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [StateId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Customer_dbo.Country_CountryId] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Country] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Customer_dbo.State_StateId] FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State] ([Id])
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State] (
    [StateId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryID] INT           NOT NULL,
    [StateName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_State_Country] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Country] ([CountryId])
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country] (
    [CountryId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CountryId] ASC)
);

Comment: This is the SQL i have used to create the tables ( leaving code first ). Here CountryID is on Both Customer as well as State. Can you advice me on the best practices I should follow

Comment: Cascade deletes mean that if I delete an item in Table1 then related items in Table2 are deleted too. So for example if I had User and UserPasswords it would make sense to delete the passwords when I deleted the user, so cascade deletions make sense there. Make the decision based on the relationship between your entities. I tend to switch it off by default, but enable it in the ( relatively few ) places it makes sense.