# How to create a foreign relation to one Model from multiple other models using Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

I am trying to create my first app using ASP.NET MVC framework and Entity Framework 6.

I chose to use code first approach and I started by defining my Models.

I have a model called `Client` with an identity attribute called `Id`. I have multiple Models that has an attribute called `ClientId`. The `ClientId` attribute should have virtual link to the `Clients` Model.

Here is how my `Client` model looks like

```
[Table("clients")]
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modified_at { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        status = "Active";
        created_at = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Then here is how I am creating a belong to relation using other models.

```
[Table("BaseClientsToUsers")]
public class ClientToUser : ModelDefault
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int DefaultTeamId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? JoinedAt { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public ClientToUser()
    {
        DateTime UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        IsActive = true;

        CreatedAt = UtcNow;

        LastUpdatedAt = UtcNow;
    }



    [Table("BaseTeams")]
    public class Team : ModelDefault
    {
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Client")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public Team()
        {
            DateTime UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

            IsActive = true;

            CreatedAt = UtcNow;

            LastUpdatedAt = UtcNow;
        }
    }
```

But, when I try to update my databases I get the following error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.BaseTeams_dbo.BaseClients_ClientId' on table 'BaseTeams' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I am not really sure what could be causing the error but it seems it is because I am creating multiple Foreign keys to the same `Clients model.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489676/entity-framework-how-to-solve-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multi)?

Comment: Thank you for the provided resources. I am still not clear how I am creating a circular cascading in the above models. All I am trying to do is create hadOne, BelongsTo, and hasMany relation

Comment: I tried to disable all the On Delete Cascade but I can't seems to do it right. Here is what I have added to my context class `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasKey(p => p.Client)
                                       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }` but I get currely red lined under WillCascadeOnDelete!

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Mike A When I started MVC I got this error too, so you need aditional  tables that connects your DB items.
So try connect your database items with tables like that:
Here is my  working example:

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal InternalPrice { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

[Table("Categories")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductCategories")]
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

So you can  connect your items without problems hope this will help  you.